# Arrange a single item inside a LazyColumn by using weight modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

I am looking to have a result like this. Two block with 2/3 size and 1/3 size respectively.

[image]

I am getting the expected result with this code.

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun LayoutCheck() {

Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .weight(3f),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
    ) {}
    Surface(
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .weight(1f),
        color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
    ) {}
    }
}
```

But when i put that inside a lazycolumn, nothing seems working. Not even getting a display.

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun LayoutCheck() {
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        contentPadding = PaddingValues(20.dp)
    ) {
        item {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(200.dp)
                        .weight(3f),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.primary
                ) {}
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .width(200.dp)
                        .weight(1f),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
                ) {}
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

If i remove t he weight and put some height,it works. But i don't want to hardcode there. So how to make it work with weight. Expecting some help..

Thanks

NB: I want scroll functionality, that's why going with `LazyColumn`

**Real World scenario :**
A Login Screen, with Logo at the first 2/3 portion and a Text and Button at the bottom 1/3 portion

**Scenario 1 : Working Perfectly:**

[image]

**Scenario 2:** If users font is bigger or screen is rotated, they wont be able to see the button

[image]

Comment: Do you have a list of items?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti No. Only one item. Its a Splash Screen, with Logo at the first 2/3 portion and a Text and Button at the bottom 1/3 portion

Comment: And why would you need a lazy column for a splash screen?

Comment: @Shijilal You can achieve it with a simple Column, but it is not clear why this screen should have a scroll. In any case you are using 3/4 and 1/4 (not 2/3 and 1/3)

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti. Sorry its not a Splash Screen. Its login Screen. The text in the bottom is for any error messages and other info. So chances are there, the text to be bigger. And in  that case one wont be able to see the Button. Same is the case if you rotate the screen.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Sorry its not a Splash Screen. Its login Screen. My bad

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Added more details in the main post to understand the issue better.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov Added more details in the main post to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You prevent the text from being resized by applying the `weight` modifier. Instead, I suggest that you make the element spacing flexible, like this:

```kotlin
Column(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    Image(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.my_image),
        contentDescription = "",
    )
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1.35f))
    Text(
        "Your app is being reviewed",
    )
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(0.2f))
    Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
        Text("Log out")
    }
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(0.2f))
}
```

Spacers explanation:

[image]

Comment: Scrolling is not happening in here.

Comment: Added more details in the main post to understand the issue better.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have only one item just use a `Column` with a verticalScroll:

```
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .verticalScroll(scrollState),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
) {
    //...
}
```

Also if you want 2/3 and 1/3, use in the 1st `Surface` the `weight(2f)` modififer.

Comment: Added more details in the main post to understand the issue better.